# Set up connection between azure redis cache and azure kubernetes service

Tags: django, azure, azure-devops, azure-aks

Please help me in setting up the connection between azure redis cache and aks. I am building an application where I would like to deploy it in aks and add redis as a service.

Answer (score 4):

You don't connect Azure Redis to AKS, your containers running on AKS will connect to the Azure Cache for Redis instance.  When connecting to an Azure Cache for Redis instance, cache clients need the host name, ports, and a key for the cache. Some clients might refer to these items by slightly different names. You can retrieve this information in the Azure portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you for your response. I have dockerized the application and want database, celery, and redis to be deployed as a service in AKS.